# ffmpeg timing metadata values differ from the ffprobe output

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

When printing the `ffmetadata` metadata of an audio file with the `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -f ffmetadata FFMETADATAFILE
```

the approximation of the timing values fields `start` and `end` in the `[CHAPTER]` object:

```
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=533975
END=586975
title=Meltdown/Spectre patched
```

is different from the same timing metadata, obtained using the `JSON` output with `ffprobe` the command:

```
ffprobe -i INPUT.mp4 -show_chapters -print_format json
```

that is

```
  {
        "id": 2,
        "time_base": "1/1000",
        "start": 534000,
        "start_time": "534.000000",
        "end": 587000,
        "end_time": "587.000000",
        "tags": {
            "title": "Meltdown/Spectre patched"
        }
    }
```

where `start_time` is `start` and `end_time` is `end` of the `ffmpeg` output. Is there a way to handle the timing info the `ffprobe` metadata output?